# Match dissimilar items inside a list in python

Tags: python

Whats the best way to match dissimilar items in a list in Python 2.7, I have

```
list= [('A', 6L), ('B', 7L), ('C', 8L), ('D', 8L), ('E', 6L), ('F', 8L)]
```

And I want to match the result like this

```
new list = ('A', 6L, 'B', 7L), ('C', 8L, 'E', 6L), ('D', 8L), ('F' 8L)]
```

where any unmatched items are at the end of the list in this case D and F.

EDIT: By matching dissimilar I mean joining each tuple (e.g (A, 6)) with another tuple where the second item in the tuple (e.g. 6) is not the same. So (A,**6**) and (B,**7**) but not (A, **6**) and (E,**6**)

Comment: Sorry, I have *no idea* what you mean by 'dissimilar' here.

Comment: What are matching criteria?

Comment: updated to make my question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to maximize the number of matches (unlike the example), you could sort the list and match items from both ends.

```
import operator
oldlist = [('A', 6L), ('B', 7L), ('C', 8L), ('D', 8L), ('E', 6L), ('F', 8L)]
newlist = []

oldlist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
while oldlist and oldlist[0][1] != oldlist[-1][1]:
    newlist.append(oldlist.pop(0) + oldlist.pop())
newlist.extend(oldlist)  #unmatched items
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you don't have duplicates, something like this should work:

```
available = set(your_original_list)
matching = []
while len(available) > 0:
    first = available.pop()
    current_set = set()
    current_set.add(first)
    for possible_match in available.copy():
        if matches(first, possible_match):
            current_set.add(possible_match)
            available.remove(possible_match)

    matching.append(current_set)
```

Of course it's up to you to implement the `matches(a, b)` function. You can sort the `matching` list at the end by the length of set in each element. (`matching.sort(lambda a,b: len(b)-len(a))`)